# making exe form HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, exe

I was wondering I have PHP based server side stuff that accepts ajax requests and sends back JSON for JS. And I have HTML and JS based "client" now I would like to create exe(windows aplication) that would look the same as the "client" in browser but without browser. Preferably somehow grab that HTML and JS and "compile it" to regural client that would still send out AJAX calls and procesing JSON data.

Edit:
To clarify things:
Server(on webserver) is PHP procesing incoming AJAX calls and diplaing JSON as result.

Client(what I want to convertt to exe) is HTML and JS(Jquery) page(application).

I want for user to have option two to dowload client for windows so he/she dont have to use browser.

Comment: Send JSON data to Server You need to have WebService to talk with Server. Also try to Create WindowsFormApplication (C#)/ Java (Swing) Application looks like ur WebSite.

Comment: well its posible to have C# app that sends out AJAX request just like browser?

Comment: See there is no ajax Response concept in GUI Programming. For Windows GUI, there is no POstback also each action will update Instantly on eahc Ui component such way you have to Create Application, and you can do one thing, using WebService you can Send Out the JSOn data to Server .

Answer (score 0):

With https://electron.atom.io/ from Github you can develop Windows, Mac and Linux applications with Javascript, Html and CSS. You can also build mobile application with your web development skills. https://cordova.apache.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Electron, but if you just want something quick and easy to use, try [Scriptonit](https://scriptonit.deneskellner.com). It's exactly for this kind of use. (Check out the documentation and the examples to see if this is the one for you.)

It's basically one exe plus a few sidecar files in a folder called `app/`, then it just works like a local browser without the frames & head. Also, it can access local files and run OS commands, even capture their output.

*Side note 1: Yes it's mine, as you can see on the link - but no, that's not why I'm recommending it

Side note 2: It's 0.9 so it's not perfect, let me know if it misbehaves.*

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can make a desktop application with markup languages. but then am also a newbie in this stuff but what I think you need is to develop a GUI in a programming language like java for example Swing docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ to mimic the apearance of your webpage. Then connect to your server by socket programming.

Comment: well socets are exactly what I am tring to avoid. since the PHP is basicly "clever" DB gateway siting on URL